# How to properly put lables on a faceted pie chart in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, pie-chart

So i have data like this:

```
tag  team   count    pct
E       A      12   1.00
E       B       5    .50
E       C       1    .20
I       B       5    .50
I       C       4    .80
```

I want to make a **faceted pie chart** with this data but I cannot get the text labels to appear in appropriate positions on the plot....what am I doing wrong here...

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(1), y = pct, fill = tag)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void()+ # remove background, grid, numeric labels
  facet_wrap(~team)+
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%1.2f%%", 100*pct)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track!

Minor adjustments:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), y = pct, fill = tag)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
    coord_polar("y", start=0) +
    theme_void()+ # remove background, grid, numeric labels
    facet_wrap(~team)+
    geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%1.2f%%", 100*pct)),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
    coord_polar(theta = 'y')
```

Need to include `position= position_stack(vjust = 0.5)` and `coord_polar(theta = 'y')`

[image]